# Apache Connection Reset with preg_split

Tags: php, apache, connection, reset, preg-split

I'm facing a very weird behavior with Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) and PHP/5.4.10,

I have this code

```
$content = <<<EOF
<UNICODE-WIN>
<Version:7><FeatureSet:InDesign-R2L><ColorTable:=<Black:COLOR:CMYK:Process:0,0,0,1>>
<DefineCharStyle:Character Style 1=<Nextstyle:Character Style 1><cTypeface:Bold Italic><cSize:19.000000><cCase:All Caps><cPosition:Normal><cKashida:Default>>
<DefineParaStyle:Paragraph Style 1=<Nextstyle:Paragraph Style 1><cTypeface:Bold Italic><cCase:All Caps>>
<DefineParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle=<Nextstyle:NormalParagraphStyle>>
<ParaStyle:Paragraph Style 1><CharStyle:Character Style 1>Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample
<CharStyle:><ParaStyle:Paragraph Style 1>
<ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle><CharStyle:Character Style 1>
<CharStyle:><ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle>Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample .
<CharStyle:><ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle>aa aaaaa aaaa  \\\<bbbbbbb\\\\\>cccccc
<ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle>
Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample
<ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle><CharStyle:Character Style 1>Text Sample
<CharStyle:><ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle>
Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample
<ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle>Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample
<ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle><CharStyle:Character Style 1><cNextXChars:Column>
<CharStyle:><ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle><cNextXChars:Column>
<ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle>Text Sample Text Sample
<ParaStyle:NormalParagraphStyle>
EOF;
$regex         = '/((<(([^<>]|<[^<>]*>)*)>\s*)+)/s';
$parts         = preg_split( $regex, $content, null, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
```

And for some reason when I execute this code it results in connection reset page in the browser, no error log in Apache or PHP

Did some research online but could not find good solution for it,

Here's a link of the [results of phpinfo page on the Windows server](http://comstrike.com/01-phpinfo.html)

Also please ntoe that I run the same code on other servers Windows and CentOS and it works just fine

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by increasing ThreadStackSize to 8 MB instead of its default Windows value of 1 MB, you just need to add these lines into Apache conf file

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```